# karaf log level for a bundle

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

How do I set a different log level for a specific bundle from karaf> prompt?

`log:set TRACE` sets TRACE level logging for all. I want INFO/DEBUG for ROOT and TRACE level logging for a specific bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't from prompt. For this you'll need to alter the org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file. Either by altering the file directly or by using the config:* commands.

Comment: I know how to do it by changing pax file.
When you mention `config:*` commands, then it means it is possible from karaf command prompt, is that correct?

Comment: yes, also look at the documentation for the config:* commands: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.x/commands/config-edit.html

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
 log:set <level> <package>
```

typed in the console karaf.